# How to access only Servlet2 if path is /Servlet1/Servlet2

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets

Suppose I want to have path look like this
    /Servlet1?id=34/Servlet2

I want to access Servlet2 depending on the id parameter received in Servlet1, but when I try to do so system access service methods of Servlet1 only and do not go to Servlet2

I just want to skip the code for Servlet1 and move to Servlet2 when my path is **/Servlet1?id=34/Servlet2** otherwise run code in Servlet 1 when path is **/Servlet1?id=34**

I am not sure when such approach is to be used, where you access a Servlet which is like a descendent to another servlet. If I am taking any concept wrong kindly correct or else suggest some solution to make it work

**EDIT:** If user enters **/Servlet1?id=34** then it shows an entirely different page and when user enters **/Servlet1?id=34/Servlet2** I want to show a different page based on the **id** specified in Servlet1.

Problem is that the URI that I get in Servlet1 when user enter path **/Servlet1?id=34/Servlet2** is only **/Servlet1** i.e. Servlet2 is nowhere in URI so how do I identify which Servlet user is looking for?

Comment: Keep a check in Servlet1 if (id == 34) then redirect to servlet2.

Answer (score 0):

Use `RequestDispatcher("\servlet2")`'s `forward(req,res)` method from `Servlet1` to forward the control to `Sertvlet2`.

Edit:

```
public class Servlet1 extends HttpServlet{

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)   throws ServletException, IOException {

    String id= request.getParameter("id");
    /*
     * You can do any processing here. 
     * We will simply output the value of name parameter on server console.
     * 
     */


         if(id.equals("32")){
      RequestDispatcher rd =
          getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("\Servlet2");
          rd.forward(request, response);
        }
}
```

}

Comment: But how will I identify when user want to access Servlet2 and when he wants to access Servlet1. Because the URI that I receive in Servlet1 is **/Servlet1** when my path is **/Servlet1/Servlet2**

Comment: you have to set some parameters in jsp/html page and send it to a `Servlet` say servlet1. Retrieve the parameter in servlet1 and according to the parameter value you can forward the control to either Servlet2 or Servlet3.

Comment: it means there is no way in servlet itself to identify whether the user wants to access the same servlet or any servlet situated down under it?

Comment: you can also map the path "/servlet1/servlet2" in web.xml to servlet2 class.

Comment: u mean url-pattern then I already set /Servlet1/Servlet2 as the url-pattern for Servlet2 but it access Servlet1 only

Comment: see your path /Servlet1?id=34/Servlet2 .in your url-pattern    /Servlet1/Servlet2 there is no id attribute. try to append id at the end of path like  /Servlet1/Servlet2?id=34

Comment: @ZazGmy: Thanks, you get me right. I can not specify parameters in Servlet1 otherwise it will take everything after id as param value